# Why is my SQL statement taking so long

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am currently trying to export some data from my (mysql) database using a php script, although i have also tried the sql statement directly in the sql section in phpmyadmin with same result.

What i am trying to do is export each unique product from my database, along with the cheapest totalprice, where there is stock and the price (cost) is more than 0, ie where quantity > 0 and price > 0

So, i thought i had figured it out with some help, and it seems to work with a small dataset, but i have about 500,000 rows in this table at the moment, and it will grow.

So my statement is:

```
SELECT 
products.name,
products.price,
products.quantity,
products.totalprice
FROM
products INNER JOIN
  (SELECT name, MIN(totalprice) min_price
   FROM products
   WHERE quantity>0 AND price>0
   GROUP BY name) m
  ON products.name=m.name AND products.totalprice=min_price
```

In phpmyadmin, it just comes up with the "loading" status, as you would expect, but then never actually gives me any values. I then have to "stop" mysql and apache (im using xampp) and then restart them, else i cannot do anything in the database.

If anyone can see what is wrong with the statement it would be great to hear any suggestions.

EDIT

I already tried simple sql statements, but they dont seem to give me the correct answers. For example i already tried:

```
SELECT name, MIN(totalprice) min_price, quantity
   FROM products
     WHERE quantity>0 AND totalprice>0
   GROUP BY name
```

But as you will see from my sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dd9f4/7/0

This gives me incorrect values, that is to say it gives me the cheapest price that has a quantity of more than 0, but the returns for quantity, the first value in the list that has a quantity of more than 0, hence why i have had to join products with products
Thanks

Comment: Did you run the `EXPLAIN` command to see which indexes are used?

Comment: @AgRizzo there are no indexes

Comment: Query seems to be okay but one thing that I can notice is using name aliasing here. I had a query before, things went to be correct but mysql went down every time I executed the query. But when I used `as` keyword all things worked! that was so weird, and here in your case it goes to be `AS m`. *maybe* it help!

Comment: Add some indexes. I would try one index on 'name' and see what happens

Comment: @revo this didnt work, still just hangs

Comment: What's the difference between `price` and `totalprice` here? Is `totalprice` just `price*quantity`?

Comment: "there are no indexes" - there you go. Indexes are invaluable.

Comment: @user1618143 price = cost price totalprice = cost * markup. Totalprice is already calculated at time of import

Comment: @AgRizzo without sounding stupid but why the need for the index. I will give it a go, but, from what i have read: "indexes can quickly determine the position to seek to in the middle of the data file without having to look at all the data", however,  "If you need to access most of the rows, it is faster to read sequentially, because this minimizes disk seeks". In my eyes, i do need to look at all the data, because the table in question is a dump of all of my supplier's inventory, which includes brand, mpn, price & stock. My "name" column ="brand"&"mpn".

Comment: The reason indexes are important here is the `group by` and the `join`. Grouping on an indexed field is sometimes faster, because it can look at all of the 'item1's, then all the 'item2's, and so on, rather than looking at them sequentially and sticking them into the appropriate bucket. A join on an unindexed field means that for every row in one table, MySQL has to look at every row in the other table. Performance goes down fast when that happens. An index on `quantity` and `price` would help, too, since it would let you filter out the zeros faster.

Comment: Also, going back to your assessment "I do need to look at all the data" : While True, your query consists of a JOIN which is MySQL needing to "align or group your data".  As a rule of thumb, put an index on the fields that make up a JOIN (usually the foreign key).  Let us know if it sped it up.  Indexes serve one purpose: Making READs faster (at the cost of WRITEs - but that is a longer conversation)

Comment: @AgRizzo I was just about to say, that whilst the export now works great, and does not take too long, the importing of data now takes more than twice as long. Before, an import of 20,000 rows took seconds, while now it takes minutes. 20,000 is about my smallest dataset that im importing into this table, with the average being 150k - 350k. Are there any other work arounds? I thought i saw once an import script that removed keys before import then put them back in. Thanks again for all your help everyone

Comment: Exactly, drop the indexes before the import, then recreate them for the export.  You are stuck optimizing for either read performance or write performance.  You can't have both, otherwise the MySQL team would have implemented it for us :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this query returns what you want (using a subquery instead of a join).  It's pretty quick in the fiddle.  Will this execute quickly enough in your DB?  You will still probably need indexes if it's big.

```
select name, totalprice, quantity
from products P
where totalprice > 0
and totalprice = 
(select min(totalprice) 
                     from products where name = P.name 
                     and quantity > 0)
```

Comment: Just a note here...if you have two records where the name is the same and the totalprice is the same, this will only return one of them.  If you want to sum quantity in that case, you can do that but just be aware of the limitation on this example.

Comment: If you do this, be sure you add an index on `(name, quantity)`, or at least `name`. You really don't want the subquery to have to scan the entire table once for every record in the table, which is what it does if there's a `where` clause but no relevant index.